# Do these iPhone log messages indicate spyware?

Tags: ios

I've seen these messages in my iPhone log and I was wondering whether someone is using spyware on my iPhone:

```
{"message":{"Accel":1,"Baseband":1,"Bt":1,"Duration":1,"DurationExitFromNoHints":1,"Gps":1,"VehicularDuration":3300,"Wifi":1},
"name":"VehicularStateDetectionLatencyStats","uuid":"6101aa5f-34b5-456c-b761-e4dea7fcd935"}
{"message":{"Accel":2,"Baseband":2,"Bt":2,"Duration":2,"DurationExitFromNoHints":2,"Gps":2,"VehicularDuration":3360,"Wifi":2},
"name":"VehicularStateDetectionLatencyStats","uuid":"6101aa5f-34b5-456c-b761-e4dea7fcd935"}
```

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different :) Please consider [editing](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/334815/edit) your question and clearly specify your query. If your question is regrading software development or coding, consider asking it on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com) to get helpful answers.

Comment: Firstly, welcome to Ask Different! Just to add to Nimesh Neema's comment, the way your question is currently worded makes it very hard for us to understand what you're asking. We'd love to help, but we have no idea where you've copied that content from or where you saw it displayed, nor the context behind it? At present all we know is that you've added the iOS tag to your question, so providing more details will help us to help you. :)

Comment: It was in my system logs I was wondering what it means  as in if ther is someone using spyware on my phone

Comment: @PaulJefferys Hi Paul, where exactly have you seen these log entries? This post describes similar messages (https://forums.macrumors.com/threads/iphone-analytics.2119511/), they are most probably harmless analytics/diagnostics data collected by Apple. You can check whether you are sharing analytics and diagnostics data with Apple by following the steps described in this support document: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT202100.

Answer (score 2):

No, these messages do not indicate that anyone is using spyware on your iPhone.

These messages are indication of the Apple provided software is functioning as it should collecting analytics/diagnostics data stored on your phone. This is not an indication of anything malicious.

Comment: However it is still possible that there actually is spyware on the iPhone. But yes, I agree, these messages are not an indication as they have no relation to spyware directly

Comment: Noone said it wasn’t a possibility. However these specific messages makes it no more or no less likely that the phone has spyware.

Answer (score -1):

I would say yes, someone is watching everything we do and store it for later. Like if you have Google Maps authorities could pull up your car or how fast your going ect...or maybe it’s your Ins watching your patterns???

Comment: This has no connection to Google maps